# Create data for all dates in a date range

Tags: sql

Here is the input dataset I have with revenue for some of the days:

[image]

Would need an output with all dates between 03/01/2021 to 03/15/2021. $0 revenue where the value is not present

[image]

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: You should create a `Dates` table that holds a record for every date. Then simply use that as your left table and instead of selecting date from the main table you would select Date from the Dates table and select the other two columns from the main table.

Comment: @Michael But that wouldn't create 15 records each for both zips

Comment: @ShubhamA yes you are correct. However, you could join to each zip separately and then union it together. How many zips do you  have? Maybe you also need a zipcode table.

Comment: @ShubhamA tag your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two additional helper tables:

- a `Dates` table that holds all the dates in the desired range, and
- a `Zipcodes` table that holds the distinct zip codes.

Instead of physical tables, temporary tables and/or table variables, you could also consider using table expressions (subqueries in the FROM-clause) or common table expressions (in a WITH-clause). Common table expressions can often also be recursive, which might be a nice solution for creating a value range with specific start and end values (like your dates range here).

It is already pointed out, that concrete solution proposals heavily depend on the target DBMS. Sadly, it is unspecified here (at the time of writing this answer). Below is a sample implementation for Microsoft SQL Server, using `T` as the placeholder for your actual table name. It uses two common table expressions: a recursive CTE for the `Dates` table and a normal CTE for the `Zipcodes` table.

```sql
WITH
  [Dates] AS (
    SELECT CAST('2020-03-01' AS DATE) AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
    FROM [Dates]
    WHERE [Date] < '2020-03-15'
  ),
  [ZipCodes] AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Zip] FROM T
  )
SELECT D.[Date], Z.[Zip], COALESCE(T.[Revenue], 0) AS [Revenue]
FROM
  [Dates] AS D
  CROSS JOIN [ZipCodes] AS Z
  LEFT JOIN T ON T.[Date] = D.[Date] AND T.[Zip] = Z.[Zip]
ORDER BY Z.[Zip], D.[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your RDBMS, it's probably going to be implemented differently in different systems. E.g. in the SQL Server there's a `master.dbo.spt_values` table, which can potentially be used for that:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(day, d.number, '2021-03-01') as Date,
  zips.Zip,
  IsNull(t.Revenue, 0) as Revenue
FROM master.dbo.spt_values d
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(Zip) FROM Table) zips
  LEFT JOIN Table t
    ON DATEADD(day, d.number, '2021-03-01') = t.Date
    AND zips.Zip = t.Zip
WHERE d.type = 'P'
  AND d.number < 15
ORDER BY zips.Zip, d.number
```

It's somewhat of a hack though

Comment: I would personally consider using a recursive CTE (instead of the ancient and undocumented `spt_values` table) to generate a specific range of subsequent values.

Comment: I would love to learn to do it as well, consider posting an example to educate us